# How to authenticate users in LDAP with password crypted md5 to use radius

Tags: radius

I have set up freeradius with authentication agains LDAP.
 I use a radius server to authenticate my users.
The problem is I cannot make the radius server read md5 encrypted passwords, 
Any idea what to do to make it read md5 passwords?